# Saving plain NSArray with NSNumbers

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

I am stumped here. I am just trying to save an NSArray populated with either NSNumbers or NSStrings to NSUserDefaults. Weird thing is it works if I save it right before I read it - but if I don't save it and read it (after it has been saved on a prior launch) it is nil. It is like the defaults are being wiped out each time I hit Run (Command-R) in XCode.

```
NSArray *arrayToSave = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], [NSNumber numberWithInt:3], nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:arrayToSave forKey:@"TestKey"];  //if I comment this line arrayRead will be nil even after I had saved it with this line on a prior run
```

Read it:

```
NSArray *arrayRead = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: @"TestKey"];
NSLog(@"arrayRead: %@", arrayRead);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call [`synchronize`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000318-CIHDDEGI) after writing to user defaults:

```
// Write
NSArray *arrayToSave = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], [NSNumber numberWithInt:3], nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:arrayToSave forKey:@"TestKey"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

// Read
NSArray *arrayRead = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"TestKey"]; // or arrayForKey
NSLog(@"arrayRead: %@", arrayRead);
```

Comment: Well I'll be! I never needed synchronize before - but that's what the Dr. ordered. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Save:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
NSMutableArray *arr = ... ; // set value 
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:arr]; 
[defaults setObject:data forKey:@"TestKey"];
```

Load:

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
    NSData *data = [defaults objectForKey:@"TestKey"]; 
    NSArray *arr = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```